# Discord help command - args.join isn't a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

with my discord bot I am working on a help command. 
My command list file which the help command accesses is:

```
{
    "Help": {
        "name":"Help",
        "group":"User",
        "desc":"Displays a list of commands",
        "usage":"help [group OR command]"
    },

    "Purge": {
        "name":"Purge",
        "group":"Admin",
        "desc":"Deletes a specified number of messages",
        "usage":"Purge <amount>"
    }
}
```

These just define group, name, and usage of the commands. The code for the help command so far is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const weather = require('weather-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const commands = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/commands.json', 'utf8'))
const token = "<my token>"
const prefix = 'cb!';

bot.on('message', message => {

    // Variables
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let sender = message.author;
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let args = cont.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix+'help')) {

            console.log('ok i hate this')

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(0x1D82B6)



            let commandsFound = 0;

            for (var cmd in commands) {

                if (commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase() === 'USER') {
                    commandsFound++

                    embed.addField(`${commands[cmd].name}`, `**Description:** ${commands[cmd].desc}\n**Usage:** ${prefix + commands[cmd].usage}`);
                }


            }

            embed.setFooter(`Currently showing user commands. To view another group do ${prefix}help [group / command]`)
            embed.setDescription(`**${commandsFound} commands found** - <> means required, [] means optional`)

            message.author.send({embed})
            message.channel.send({embed: {
                color: 0x1D82B6,
                description: `**Check your DMs ${message.author}!**`
            }})

            } else {
                // Variables
                let groupFound = '';

                for (var cmd in commands) {

                    if (args.join(" ").trim().toUpperCase() === commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase()) {
                        groupFound = commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase();
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if (groupFound != '') {
                    for (var cmd in commands) {

                        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setColor(0x1D82B6)



                        let commandsFound = 0;

                        if (commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase() === groupFound) {
                            commandsFound++

                            embed.addField(`${commands[cmd].name}`, `**Description:** ${commands[cmd].desc}\n**Usage:** ${prefix + commands[cmd].usage}`);
                        }


                    }

                    embed.setFooter(`Currently showing ${groupFound} commands. To view another group do ${prefix}help [group / command]`)
                    embed.setDescription(`**${commandsFound} commands found** - <> means required, [] means optional`)

                    message.author.send({embed})
                    message.channel.send({embed: {
                        color: 0x1D82B6,
                        description: `**Check your DMs ${message.author}!**`
                    }})

                }



    }

});
```

If I were to type "cb!help admin" I would get this error in the console

```
                    if (args.join(" ").trim().toUpperCase() === commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase()) {
                             ^

TypeError: args.join is not a function
```

What might I do to fix this? I've also tried `if (args[0].join...` but that doesn't work.

As always, thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm basing this off of out dated code so there are maybe some other errors. I'm trying too fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

`args` has one definition in your code sample:

```
let args = cont.shift().toLowerCase();
```

This makes args a `string` - `string` do not have the method `join()` as `join()` is part of the Array prototype chain, which strings do not inherit from. `shift()` will return the first element of the `cont` array, so you may just want to call `args.toUpperCase()`, although I would recommend renaming your variables to make the meaning of what `args` is clearer.

Comment: so what should I do exactly? Would ```(arguments.join(" ").trim().toUpperCase() === commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase())``` work?

Comment: Based on what I *think* your code is doing, you'll want to remove the call to `join()`. It sounds like you just want to compare the first argument (presumably the command) to a set of commands you have stored. If that's the case, then removing `join()` will do that just fine. `join()` is meant to... join.. an array of elements into a single string. You already *have* a single string.

Comment: Okay I'll try and get back to you in a sec

Comment: Now I don't get an error, but it still doesn't send the group specified. Would you mind using a chat to help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to swap your two variables at the top so that

```js
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
let cont = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Then just put args in your if statement

```js
if (args[0].toUpperCase === commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase) { /* Your code... */ }
```

Your args are already stored in an array so there is no need to trim them and the join function is also therefore not needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your missing client, insert `client, message, args`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.